# Issue while calling action method with ajax contentType

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that need to post back through Ajax. Getting problem while calling the `ActionMethod`. below are the code.

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult AjaxTest(object name)
    {
        return Json("Welcome" + name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Cstml :

```
<form name="frmTest" method="POST">
@Html.Label("Your name Please")
@Html.TextBox("username")
<input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
```

JQuery :

```
$(function () {
    $("form[name='frmTest']").submit(function (e) {
        var name = $('#username').val();
      $.ajax(
      {
          type: "POST",
          //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "MyTest/AjaxTest",
          dataType: "json",
          data: { name:name },
          success: function (data, status) {
              alert("Pass"+data);
          },
          error: function () {
              alert("Fail");
          }
      });
  });

});
```

By using the above code break point hit to `AjaxTest` with the parameter. when I use `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` then the page postedback without hitting the break point.
But both cases I got fail alert. unable to find the issue,

Comment: may I ask why you are going all the way to the server to simply Add the "Welcome" to name?

Comment: You are trying to submit a form while sending some ajax, I think it's one or the oher, not both at the same time.

Comment: @CodingYoshi thnx , This is a demo application of my main application

Comment: @JorgeF thnx, in the AjaxTest i want to insert data to db, then what is the best approach.

Comment: @JorgeF the event handler happens prior to the actual submission of the form so its ok to do so.

Comment: can you change your error part to this so you can see what the error is: error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }

Comment: @CodingYoshi getting blank in error

Comment: You don't need `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` (and if you did include it, then it needs to be `data: JSON.stringify({ name:name }),` You have also not cancelled the default submit (using `e.preventDefault();`) so you making both an normal submit and an ajax submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but since in one of the comments you stated you will be saving stuff to the database, normally, in ASP MVC it would be done like this.

Create a class for whatever you will be posting using AJAX. For example, in this example, I created a class called Person

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your form you can have something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

<form name="frmTest" method="POST">
    @Html.Label("Your name Please")
    @Html.TextBox("username")
    <input class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("form[name='frmTest']").submit(function (e) {
            var name = $('#username').val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "AjaxTest",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "Age": 55, "Name": name },
                success: function (data, status) {
                    alert("Pass" + data);
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert("Fail" + ex);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Then have an action which the JSON will be submitted to. For the above, the action will be like this:

```
public JsonResult AjaxTest(Person person)
{
    return Json("Welcome" +  person.Name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

ASP MVC will take care of the binding for you. Please also note the url I am posting is "AjaxTest" and it will post to AjaxTest action method of the controller which served the form.

If you have a controller like below, then all of the above will work.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // This returns the view with the form
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult AjaxTest(Person person)
    {
        return Json("Welcome" +  person.Name, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it is working as per your exception? Do you mean expectation? Yes e.preventDefault will stop the submission of the form as that is the default behaviour

Comment: Sorry expectation*